# С++ поразрядная сортировка двоичных чисел

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

Суть задачи заключается в том, чтобы отсортировать массив, состоящий из двоичных чисел поразрядно от большего разряда к меньшему.

Сортировка происходит по следующему алгоритму: все числа упорядочиваются по цифре в самом старшем разряд, для этого массив просматривается от начала (ищется число с 1 в заданном разряде) и конца (ищется число с 0 в заданном разряде) к середине и выбирается пара чисел для обмена. В результате массив разбивается на две части с 0 и 1 в старших разрядах, к каждой из которых применяется сортировка по цифре в разряде правее (при равенстве этих цифр сохранять упорядоченность по цифре в "предыдущем" разряде); и так далее до самого младшего разряда. В основе алгоритма поразрядной сортировки лежит абстрактная операция извлечения цифры в заданном разряде. Алгоритм рекурсивный. Код написан на C++.

Проблема в следующем: сортируются сначала числа с нулями, а затем с единицами, то есть при вводе массива [101010, 101, 1, 0, 111111] он отсортируется следующим образом : [0, 101, 101010, 1, 1111111]. Как исправить код, чтобы сортировался по возрастанию?

```
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <locale.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #define N 25

    using namespace std;


    void array_input(int a[], int &max_len, int &size)//ввод массива
    {
        cout << "Введите размер массива(2-25): ";
        while (1)
        {
            cin >> size;
            if ((size < 1) || (size > N)) cout << "Размерность должна быть больше 1 и меньше 25! 
    Введите заново: ";
            else break;
        }

        cout << "Заполните массив: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) cin >> a[i];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)//поиск максимальной длины элемента массива
        {
            int counter = 0, digit = a[i];

            while (digit != 0)
            {
                counter++;
                digit /= 10;
            }
            if (counter > max_len) max_len = counter;
        }
    }

    void sort(int a[], int radix, int left, int right)
    {
        int border, middle, i_digit, j_digit;

        middle = int(left + right) / 2;//середина массива 

        for (int i = left; i < middle; i++)//движение от начала к середине массива
        {
            if (radix == 1)
            {
                if (a[i] % 10 == 1)
                {
                    for (int j = right - 1; j >= middle; j--)// движение от конца к середине
                    {
                        if (a[j] % 10 == 0)
                        {
                            int t = a[i];
                            a[i] = a[j];
                            a[j] = t;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            else if (radix > 1)
            {
                i_digit = (a[i] % int(pow(10, radix))) / int(pow(10, radix - 1));// разряд числа для сортировки от начала к середине
                if (i_digit == 1)
                {
                    for (int j = right - 1; j >= middle; j--)// движение от конца к середине
                    {
                        j_digit = (a[j] % int(pow(10, radix))) / int(pow(10, radix - 1)); // разряд числа для сортировки от конца к середине
                        if (j_digit == 0)
                        {
                            int t = a[i];
                            a[i] = a[j];
                            a[j] = t;

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (radix > 1)
        {
            for(border = left; border < right; border ++) if((a[border] % int(pow(10, radix))) / 
    int(pow(10, radix - 1)) == 1) break; // поиск границы отсортированного массива
            radix--;

            if (border == right - 1) sort(a, radix, left, right); 

            else
            {
                sort(a, radix, left, border);
                sort(a, radix, border, right);
            }
        }
    }

    int main() 
    {
        int a[N],  max_len = 0, size;
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
        array_input(a, max_len, size);
        sort(a, max_len, 0, size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) cout << *(a+i) << "\t";
        _getch();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Хочу только заметить, что реальная поразрядная сортировка идет от младшего разряда к старшему, а не наоборот...

Comment: вообще я так думаю от вас хотели увидеть сортировку на основе бинарного дерева. почитайте тут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0